# Why does x[2] reassign the y value as well? And how do I fix this

Tags: c, variables, cs50

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>

int main(void)
{

    string y, x;
    y = x = get_string();

    x[2] = '\0';

    printf("%s", x);
    printf("%s", y);

}
```

If input is `abcdef`. Output for this code is `abab`. Why is it not `ababcdef`.

Comment: Because that horrible `cs50` header typedefs a string type which hides pointer semantics.

Comment: Both x and y are pointing to the same memory location. Strings are nothing but char pointer. If you want separate copies then do strcpy.

Comment: Just get rid of cs50.h, it has repeatedly been recognized as blatant crap by many highly experienced C programmers here on SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that `get_string()` gives you a pointer on the string. So when you assigning the value in `x` and `y` you are actually pointing to a string and not storing it.
So when you change something you are affecting the string itself.
To fix it you should use `strcpy();` to copy the string so that you are not using pointer references.

Answer (score 4):

That's because `y` and `x` pointing to the same string returned by `get_string`.

[get_string](https://reference.cs50.net/cs50/get_string):

> Reads a line of text from standard input and returns it as a `string` (`char *`), sans trailing newline character. [...]

Comment: How do I stop y from being re-assigned as well

Comment: Don't assign `y = x`.   By doing that, you're forcing `y` and `x` to have the same value, which (in `y = x = get_string()`) means they point to the same address.

Answer (score 0):

You assigned the string the `NUL` terminator so `printf` will end printing when it finds it. Also `x` and `y` point to same string literal. Try this code out to understand what is happening:

```
x[2] = '\0';

for(int idx = 0; idx < 6; idx++ )
{
    if( x[idx] == '\0')
        printf("NUL");
    else
        printf("%c", x[idx]);
}
    printf("\n");
for(int idx = 0; idx < 6; idx++ )
{
    if( y[idx] == '\0')
        printf("NUL");
    else
        printf("%c", y[idx]);
}
```